# A record that depends on all other table records in sql db

Tags: sql

Assuming I have a currencies table like this one:

[image]

The table is_main column hold information about  which currency is considered "main currency".
**The table must have one main currency, but not more than one**. 
Is there an elegant way to define such condition in the sql db itself (H2 in this case) or 
would it be better to handle it using the (java) application layer?

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836704/conditional-unique-index-on-h2-database) proposed by Andy is for:
 "a column x which should be unique when the column y is not equal to 0".
I would define the need as: 
"a column x which should be unique when all other x records are equal to 0" 
 or even better: "when col x is 1 set all other x records to 0"

I prefer a generic sql solution rather than specific H2 database solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional Unique index on h2 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836704/conditional-unique-index-on-h2-database)

Comment: I am not sure it is duplicate. I don't see how can I use unique when I have multiple records with the value of 0 (where ! is_main )

Comment: Have you read post I've linked? Is it clearly said about **conditional** unique index there: "*a column `x` which should be unique when the column `y` is not equal to 0*" - that is exactly your case.

Comment: Yes, i did read it of course. It may help me in my search for what I need. Using the terminology you suggested I would define the need as: "a column x which should be unique when all other x records are equal to 0"  or even better: **  "when col x is 1 set all other  x records to 0"

Comment: @OferYuval If I understand you correctly, the difference between [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836704/conditional-unique-index-on-h2-database) and your question is you *also* want to enforce that there's *always* at least one main currency?  [Here's a duplicate on dba.se](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/how-do-i-force-one-record-to-have-a-true-value-for-a-boolean-column-and-all-oth).

Comment: Does H2 support partial indexes? Because this can easily be enforced with one.

Comment: https://github.com/etsrepo/h2database/issues/582 it does not

Comment: @Schwern yes, that is the main difference. The other small difference it that the value  of a certain record in column x, depends on the x value of all other records. Thanks for the link. it is very helpful.  +1

Answer (score 1):

I would actually save the main currency in a second table like that:

```
create table settings (key char(255), val char(255)).
```

There you store a key-value pair like main_currency='USD' or the like. You can then make queries like

```
select * from currencies left join settings where settings.val=currencies.iso_name and settings.key='main_currency'
```

Comment: Thanks @John Trash, that is what I am doing now, but I would like to try have it all in one table.

Comment: But why? Actually you waste a lot of space (speaking more in terms of logic than actual memory) when you take a whole column for an information with is just a tuple. That is usually a bad idea in database design.

Comment: good to know. Thank you I will take it into consideration and may leave the design as is. +1

Answer (score -2):

Use lowecase for ISO name of default currency for example. Or uppercase and lowercase for all other. It will be sorted at the top.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it just adds a new one. Now you need to make sure only one name is lower case AND you've got one currency whose name is formatted differently.